# Unexpected binary output

Tags: c++

I'm writing a code to add the first and last integer of a number. But the output results in binary instead of integer.
//Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int t, n;
    cin >> t;
    for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
        cin>> n;
        string s = to_string(n);
        char first = s[0];
        char last = s[s.length() - 1];
        int a = first;
        int b = last;
        cout << first + last;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output code

```
/tmp/ujHkZRfwZL.o
1
1234
101
```

Comment: Read about the [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) representation.  For example, the character `'9'` has a decimal value of `57`, not `9` like you might expect.

Comment: _But the output results in binary instead of integer_; Please provide the output

Comment: i've updated the output

Comment: and it's not giving the ascii conversation but in binary

Comment: If `/tmp/ujHkZRfwZL.o` is also part of the output I would say that you have much bigger problems!

Comment: If the input is `1234` then your program, as shown, would do `'1' + '4'` which with ASCII will be `49 + 51` which indeed is `101`. Not binary, you just haven't tested with anything else. Try e.g. `12345` instead, and the result will be `102`.

Comment: /tmp/ujHkZRfwZL.o is nothing just the online compiler that I'm using.

Comment: if its ascii so how can i get it in integer

Comment: Replace the three last lines in your loop (the definition of `a` and `b`, and the output) with the three lines shown in Vlad's answer.

Comment: @AmnRwt -- You should print out the value of `first` and `last` individually to see what everyone has been mentioning.  If you did that, then your question could have been more focused as to why you see 49 and 50.

Comment: individually it's giving the correct output but not when any operator is being used. and thankyou for your advice i'll look upto it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should at least write

```
    int a = first - '0';
    int b = last - '0';
    cout << a + b;
```

Comment: It should be noted that this subtraction "trick" is only guaranteed to work with digit characters, as it's specified in the C++ specification. There are other encodings than ASCII still in active use, where it's not possible to do this on letter characters.

Comment: thankyou that i worked i was adding first and last instead of a and b. thankyou soo much

Comment: can you explain me the use of - '0' in this line why we used it

Comment: @AmnRwt If for example the object last contains the character '4' then '4' - '0' results in integer 4. Characters that correspond to digits are follow each other.